# How can I permanent set the user environment variable - PATH using golang?

Tags: environment-variables

How can I permanently set the user environment variable - PATH using golang? 
The var set by os.Setenv function only valid in current process, thanks.

Comment: You cannot (thankfully). The only way is to modify user's profile or system settings, both would require reauthentication or reboot and both are os-specific.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. At least not in any practical sense. Yes, you could write a program (in Go, Java, Python, or any other language) which modified the relevant config files such as *~/.bashrc*. But that would be a rather silly way to solve this problem. Like killing a mosquito with a shotgun level silly.

Environment variables live in the address space of each process; i.e., they are private to each process. When a process starts a new process it will either give the new process a copy of its environment variables or a custom set of env vars. That new process can only modify its env vars. It cannot modify the env vars of its parent process -- or any other process.